# Typeahead.js not showing any results

Tags: twitter, typeahead.js, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I'm trying to get Twitter's typeahead to work, but can't figure out how. As far as my knowledge goes, I've included the files correctly, but it still won't work.

My code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app = "IndexApp">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="search"/>
    <!--jQuery-->
    <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--typeahead-->
    <script src = "./views/js/typeahead.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--index.css script-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./views/css/index.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    <!--Index.js-->
    <script src = "./views/js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').typeahead({source: states});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[JS fiddle sample (click):](https://jsfiddle.net/lalitjisoria/qyLL705h/)

```
var states = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: states
});
```